# Синхронные запросы в goLang

Tags: golang

Начинаю знакомится с goLang, возник вопрос. Как сделать синхронные запросы, по аналогии того как работают они в PHP при включенной записи в сессию? Чтоб при отправке сразу нескольких AJAX запросов, они отдавались по очереди. Как понимаю нужно каждый запрос стартовать в потоке и отдавать response после того как поток отработает.На сколько потоков можно рассчитывать на слабеньком сервере с порядка 256Мб оперативки

Чтоб вместо такой картины
[image: http://screencloud.net/v/zo92]

Была такая
[image: http://screencloud.net/v/uO7E]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы для одной сессии запросы обрабатывались строго последовательно - нужно самостоятельно делать механизм синхронизации и торможение обработки.

Например

```
var(
     SessionsMapMutex Mutex
     SessionsMap map[string]*Mutex
)

...

func RequestWorker(session_id string){
var mutex *Mutex
var ok bool
SessionsMapMutex.Lock()
if mutex, ok = SessionsMap[session_id]; !ok {
mutex = &Mutex{}
SessionsMap[session_id] = mutex
}
SessionsMapMutex.Unlock()
mutex.Lock()
defer mutex.Unlock()

Work...
}
```

Количество одновременных запросов зависит от их ресурсоемкости. Например если каждый запрос по гигабайту памяти потребует и вы это всё будете в памяти хранить - даже не один не хватит.

По количеству горутин (количество ожидающих запросов) насколько я знаю ограничений особых нет - тоже пока память не кончится. Каждая горутина на себя несколько килобайтов забирать будет.

Answer (score 2):

В golang есть такие сущности как channel. Они отлично справляются(собственно для того и были придуманы) с огранизацие синхронной обработки клиентских запросов.
Создаешь channel и пишешь в него любой входящий запрос(до или после логики) и пишешь одну функцию которая читает из этого channеl'аб и можешь быть уверен что кдиент увидит ответы в той последовательности в которой сервер их обработал.

```
func createChannel(){
    c = make(chan byte)
}

func httpRequestHandler(requestMsg []byte){
    if resJson := getResut(requestMsg); res != nil{
        c <- resJson
    }
}


func sendReplyToClient(){
    for{
        select{
            case reply, ok := <- c:
                if !ok{
                    errorhandling()
                    return
                }
                sendReplyMsgToClient(reply)
            case err, ok := <- errChannel:
                if !ok{
                    errorhandling()
                    return
                }
                sendErrorMsgToClient(reply)
        }
    }
}
```

Цикл будет скакать по каналам и как только в канале появится сообщение, вытащит его из канала и запустить обработчик из кейса. Канал - это банальная очередь с несколькими увлекательными особеностями. Весьма удобная штука.